# Texture not realistic

Tags: texturing, materials

I am currently working on a hot chocolate scene and it is going good!

[image: :D]

But when I added in some marshmallows, I encountered a problem.

[image: Eh...]

The hot marshmallows doesn't "look right" in comparison with the hot chocolate. It seems much dimmer and fake.

Is it just me, or is something wrong? Can somebody please help me make it more realistic? I don't think I'll be posting this .blend, since I don't know how to post textures with it.

Hot chocolate node setup:

[image]

Marshmallow node setup:

[image]

Comment: Although this question may entail slightly opinion-based answers, it would be much more helpful if you posted your material nodes. You gotta help us help you :)

Comment: Surface tension makes the fluid "stick" slightly to objects floating in them https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=surface+tension , marshmallows aren't totally opaque, they are probably slightly translucent, and your foam may need some slight reflections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok... As I am a new user, and have insufficient reputation points to post this as a comment (which I think is what it should be) I am reframing it as a **PARTIAL answer**, as the meta.stackexchange.com post suggests I should: (see [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174?s=0%7C0.1992#214174) )

I wanted to add to what [Duarte Farrajota Ramos](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos) said about surface tension. Remember the surface tension and the bubbles make the liquid surface non-flat, so you need the surface normals to form a dome over bubbles and to creep up around the edge of the marshmallows and cup to look real... Also good to think how the bubbles interact with each other, and with the marshmallows: The bubbles should clump togeather and eventually merge or pop, they also stick to the sides of the marshmallows and cup, but they can't occupy the same space as each other nor intersect the edges of the cup or marshmallows. You may want to look at [Jean-Francois Gallant (pyroevil)](http://pyroevil.com)'s "[Molecular Script](http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/)" blender addon to allow particles, that you may use for bubbles, liquid, and marshmallows, to interact with each other. (Standard Blender particles can interact with their environment, but not each other.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to tweak the translucency of your nodes. first your chocolate is missing it. but you need it so that you can see the marshmallows inside the chocolate. 
the marshmallows need a little bit more translucency aswell (or even try changing it with a subsurface scattering note, but im not sure).

also the marshmallows are lacking some details like flaws and scratches. you can achieve this by adding a normal/displacement mab.

Furthermore the parts near the chocolate need to look wet. to fake that, you need to create an ambient occlusion map. put the value of the map into a mix shader with a 0% roughness glossy shader. this way, the parts that are near the water are becoming shiny and thus looking wet. here is a tutorial that kinda explains it: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-quickly-add-dirt-to-crevices/