# Create a wispy, foamy top? Like Hot Cocoa?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to create a mug of hot cocoa in Blender, and right now I'm trying to perfect the fluid itself.
[image]

Here's a better picture of what I'm trying to create:
[image]

I'm trying to create this bubbly, foamy top layer to the cocoa, but I'm not sure where to start. YouTube tutorials show people commonly just use a texture as the top, but I'd like to recreate the effect completely in blender.

I might even add some whipped cream eventually, but I'm taking it slow. I know how to do the marshmallows, I'm just trying to figue out how to create the top layer.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56645/texture-not-realistic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make foam with bubbles (beer, bath)](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63812/how-to-make-foam-with-bubbles-beer-bath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick render of what you described. Here I essentially have a whole lot of bubbles on the surface of a rectangle, which is basically what the froth is. You could increase the number, size, etc of the bubbles easily, my computer just can't handle more than this :)

[image: Sample of Frothy Cocoa]

To make the large bubbles, I made a single sphere, and colored it a semi-transparent brown color. Next I duplicated it a few times and used the random transform tool *object>transform>randomize transform* as seen [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/randomly-place-and-scale-objects)

Next I made one small sphere into a group and used the particle tool (great post on that [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8927/is-there-a-way-to-procedurally-scatter-objects-on-the-ground-of-my-scene/8928#8928)) to scatter them randomly across the surface. The post I mentioned show how to use the options to make the bubbles smaller, make more, etc.

I recognize that this doesn't look exactly like hot cocoa, but if you just color the bubbles a bit differently, adding some more white and a bit of dark brown it'll be pretty close.